# File upload extension

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload multiple files with filtered extension. Even if I provide correct files I am not able to upload files. please help me to fix the problem.

`HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;`

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= hfc.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        string sFileExt1 = Path.GetExtension(hfc[i].FileName);
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            if (sFileExt1 != ".jpg" || sFileExt1 != ".jpeg")
            {
                //lblMsg.Text = "Extension not supported";
                lblMsg.Text = sFileExt1.ToString();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Special_Requests\\") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                iUploadedCnt += 1;
                lblMsg.Text = "File(s) upload successsfuly.";
            }
        }
    }
```

ayha

Comment: How are you not able to upload the files?  In what way does it fail?  When you debug this, where does it go wrong?

Comment: No error message but uploaded files in the available in the folder.

Comment: I understand that the files don't end up in the destination folder, but when you debug this where does it fail?  Are the files included in the form POST?  Do you successfully get the `sFileExt1` value?  What does that value contain?  At what point does the observed behavior of this code deviate from the expected behavior?  We can't debug this for you, you have to give us relevant runtime information.

Comment: Also it displays "Extension not supported." message.

Comment: The code stops at "Extension not supported." point. When I displayed the extension it is correct. More one upload controls are there in the form and some of them are empty.

Comment: I get the sFileExt1  value correct.

Comment: @ayha: Did you `debug` ??

Comment: Is filtering uploaded files on extension enough? What are you trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extension cannot be both a .jpg and a .jpeg simultaneously.  Basically, you're saying to fail if the extension isn't a .jpg or if the extension isn't a .jpeg.  So File.jpeg will cause a true condition (extension != jpg), and so will File.jpg (extension != jpeg)

Try `If(sFileExt1 != ".jpg" && sFileExt1 != ".jpeg")`

**Better Solution**

As pointed out in the comment, I think a better solution would be something like below (not tested):

```
List<string> validExtensions = new List<string> {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
if (validExtensions.Contains(sFileExt1.ToLower()))
{
    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Special_Requests\\") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
    iUploadedCnt += 1;
    lblMsg.Text = "File(s) upload successfully.";        
}
else
{
    //lblMsg.Text = "Extension not supported";
    lblMsg.Text = sFileExt1;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but when I add another extension it fails as follows. If(sFileExt1 != ".jpg" && sFileExt1 != ".jpeg" || sFileExt1 != ".png")

Comment: Of course it does.  Your error code will execute when the file extension isn't ".jpg", isn't a ".jpeg", OR if it's not ".png".  You need to use && in all cases.  It may be easier to replace your logic with if(sFileExt1 == ".jpg" || sFileExt1 == ".jpeg" || sFileExt1 == ".png") { ... Run valid extension code... } else { ... display invalid extension message ...}  Better would be to place your list of extensions into an array, see if the extension is in that list, and act accordingly.